# Swift: Check if username exists (Firebase V.3+)

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, block

I am working with firebase version 3+ to check if a username exists in the database.  I am stuck as it seems the `block` is being skipped as the `print` lines are not making it to the console. I will eventually have this return a bool to pass to another function.

```
 func FBaseEmailTakenVerification() {

    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

    print(ref) //Firebase location exists

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        //Nothing inside the block is running
        if snapshot.exists() {

            print("snapshot exists")

        } else {

           print("Snapshot does not exist")

        }
    })
}
```

Any help getting this `block` to run will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: tried querying the whole db without the child reference of users ? does that work ?

Comment: The new API requires you be authenticated to access data. Also verify your path exists.

Comment: @jay So if I cant access the database until being authenticated how can I check if a username is taken when I am trying to authenticate?  For example how can I access the list of usernames without being authenticated to check to see if the username is taken.  I am sure the path exists.

Comment: @Manstof My comment was pretty unclear - my apologies. *By default* with version 3, you have to be authenticated to read. You can change that in your rules by setting ".read": true and ".write": true. On the other hand you could simply rely on .createUser returning an error when the user name is already taken - there's an error code listing in the Firebase docs.